# in which situations anonymous enum should be used?

Tags: c++, c

In both c and c++ `enum` could be defined with tag

```
enum e_smth {
    smth_one,
    smth_two,
    smth_err
};
```

or without tag

```
enum {
    smth_one,
    smth_two,
    smth_err
};
```

---

If it was defined with tag it makes sense in `switch` statements in both c and c++ :

```
e_smth some_var;
....//do some stuff with some_var
switch (some_var)
{
case smth_one:
break;
case smth_two:
break;
}
```

will produce  `-Wswitch` warning if this will be compiled with gcc or g++.

It makes sense in functions declarations and variables initialization in c++ :

```
e_smth var;
var=99;
```

Will produce `-fpermissive` error if compiled with g++.

Both types with or without tag could be used as one file `#define` macro without parameters.

---

**update**

> could be used as one file `#define` macro without parameters

meant : Instead of writing `#define MAX 1000` in file and adding MAX to global use `enum { MAX=1000 }` just in file scope

---

And what about anonymous enums, I've found just one use cases:
definition like `typedef enum { a,b,c } some_t;` makes it work like enum with tag

### Question:

if I haven't yet described all reasonable use cases, what for anonymous enums should be used?

Comment: IF I recall correctly, and I'm not sure that I have this exactly, way back in the day you had to use typedef with enum's, or else use the "enum" keyword when declaring variables of the enum type. Once you've got the typedef in place, putting a tag on the enum is irrelevant, so we didn't bother. So, tl;dr: Ancient history stuff.

Comment: >  use the "enum" keyword when declaring variables
It's old good C syntax but I've corrected question because it makes no sense here @mjfgates

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In C (but not in C++), `enum` can be [ab]used to define `int` constants.

For example, given this declaration:

```
const int MAX = 1024;
```

`MAX` is not a constant expression, it's the name of a read-only object.  That means you can't use it in a case label, as the size of an array declared at file scope or with `static`, or in any other context requiring a constant expression.

But if you write:

```
enum { MAX = 1024 };
```

then `MAX` *is* a constant expression of type `int`, usable in any context where you could use the constant `1024`.

Of course you could also write:

```
#define MAX 1024
```

but there are disadvantages to using the preprocessor: the identifier isn't scoped the way it would be given an ordinary declaration, for example.

The drawback is that such a constant can only be of type `int`.

C++ has different rules; enumeration constants are of the enumerated type, not `int`, but you can use declared constant objects as constant expressions (as long as the initializer is a constant expression).

To address the original question, when you use an `enum` declaration to create constants like this, there's no point in having either a tag or a typedef, since you'll never use the type itself.

Background: This:

```
enum foo { zero, one, two };
enum foo obj = two;
```

creates a type `enum foo` and constants `zero`, `one`, and `two`.  In C, the constants are always of type `int`, which is admittedly odd, and the initialization of `obj` involves an implicit conversion from `int` to `enum foo`.

In C++, the type `enum foo` can also be referred to as just `foo`, and the constants are of type `enum foo` (which is compatible with *some* integer type, not necessarily `int`).

Comment: Another (cornercase) advantage of `enum` constants over `#defines` is that they can be defined inside a macro expansion.

Answer (score 6):

Another use case is as an element of a `struct` or `union`, typically when it doesn't make sense to use it by itself (because it's there solely to satisfy the ABI of a communication protocol or etc. and there is a more appropriate representation for programmatic use).

Comment: like `struct A {int a; enum{ e_a,e_b,e_c} state; };` ?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  There's no real reason to have a tag in that case.

Answer (score 0):

@eith Thompson

Your answer has the statement that "const int MAX = 1024;
MAX is not a constant expression,".
However, the example from the link http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression
shows that it's a constant expression and can be used in a array declaration.
Constant expressions
  C++  C++ language  Expressions 
Defines an expression that can be evaluated at compile time.

Such expressions can be used as non-type template arguments, array sizes, and in other contexts that require constant expressions, e.g.

```
int n = 1;
std::array<int, n> a1; // error, n is not a constant expression
const int cn = 2;
std::array<int, cn> a2; // OK, cn is a constant expression
```

Comment: He meant C, not C++, I believe.  If I remember correctly, C's `const` rules are a bit wonkier than C++'s, hence it not being legal to use a `const` as a compile-time constant.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you only need to name an enum when you use it more than once. In other words, if you define multiple variables using the same enum, then you need to name the enum. However, if you only use the enum once and there will only ever be one variable having that enum, then an anonymous enum makes sense. For example:

```
enum color { red, blue, gray, green };
enum color car_color;
enum color house_color;
```

Here there are multiple variables, so the enum is named.

```
typedef struct {
    int year;
    enum { Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, July, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec } month;
    unsigned int day;
} date;
```

Here the author plans to only use the enum once, so a name is unnecessary.