# Are there any plans for a future C standard after C11?

Tags: c, iso, c11

I searched on the [open standards website](http://www.open-std.org), particularly the [C working group homepage](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/) but only found information about C11.

They seem to have regular meetings and discuss different features and extensions, but they never actually mention a future C standard nor roadmap. It is hard to tell whether they are working on a new standard or just a [Technical Corrigendum](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards) to the current standard.

Comment: I *guess* after releasing a new revision of the C standard, they do work in analyzing the results of the last changes (how did the compiler integrate those new changes, what new questions arise etc…) and then agree on a "discussion" roadmap, before working on the new standard roadmap, giving it a temporary name (like `C1x`) before having a definitive name… But that's really only how I'd expect it to be.

Comment: Most probably there'll be changes to the consume memory order, but I don't think there will be many more changes coming soon, so a TC should suffice.

Comment: There is lots of stuff out there about C++14: http://www.bing.com/search?q=C%2B%2B14

Comment: What about this: http://isocpp.org/std/status  It meantions C++14 and C++17

Comment: I asked about C, not C++. The last C++ version is C++11 and the last C version is C11, they came out the same year, but I don't think they are really bound to each other.

Comment: Some people could use modifications to the updated [memory model](https://lwn.net/Articles/586838/), but I don't know of any additional major features or updates people are looking for.

Comment: The first full release of a new standard was made 10 years after the original (C99, compared with C89/C90).  The second full release of the standard was 12 years after the previous (C11, compared with C99).  There is a 5-year cycle at which standards have to be reaffirmed.  I would expect that the standard would be reaffirmed in 2016 or 2017, and work might start on the next standard shortly afterwards, with a release date in 2021 or thereabouts.  That assumes there is any pressure for new features in the standard.  Otherwise, it might simply be reaffirmed in 2021, too.

Comment: The difference between C and C++ is that there were a number of features that people wanted to get into C++11 but couldn't.  The shorter update cycle reflects their intention to try and get some of those features into the language.

Comment: It's too localized. It's about a future event and will lack relevance eventually.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I sent an email to the guy on the WG 14 contact section but I didn't expect to get an answer anytime soon, however, I did.

This is what he replied to me:

> the Committee has not discussed starting work on a new revision of the
>   Standard.  WG 14 will be meeting in Parma Italy the first part of
>   April, and so far there as not been any proposals for new features
>   that would prompt the revision process.
>
> Thanks,
>
> John Benito  - ISO/IEC JTC 1/SC 22/WG 14 Convener

So I guess this is as official as it gets for now.

Comment: I recently had cause to contact David Keaton (WG 14 Convener) in relation to this also, his response was that they were just beginning the discussion of what to do for the next version of C, and pointed me to (subject to change) http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2021.htm which mentions 2022 as the currently intended date for publication of the next full standard.

Answer (score 8):

It appears there is discussion about the next C standard, C2x, and there are proposals as well.

You can view the charter [here](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n2086.htm).

And, you can view the email list [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/).

At the bottom of the charter, it indicates an expected publication date of 2022.

Answer (score 4):

There is C18 (https://www.iso.org/standard/74528.html) standard released in June 2018 but it only addressed flaws in C11 without introducing new language features.

Answer (score 3):

A technical corrigendum is issued to correct a technical error or ambiguity. New features and extensions need to be published as an amendment or revision of the standard.

See here for an in depth description of the procedure for developing an international standard:
http://isotc.iso.org/livelink/livelink?func=ll&objId=4230452&objAction=browse&sort=subtype