# When I am using const in c language variables [TAILLE_MAX]={3,6,0,8,97,0,5,6,0,8} compiler issue "expression must have a constant value

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
const int TAILLE_MAX = 10; 
int iTableau[TAILLE_MAX]={3,6,0,8,97,0,5,6,0,8};
```

Comment: Please post all code and error messages directly in the question as text, not a picture of text and not a link to a picture of text.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>

const int TAILLE_MAX = 10;

int iTableau[TAILLE_MAX]={3,6,0,8,97,0,5,6,0,8};

int main()
{
    int* iPointeurDeb = NULL;
    int* iPointeurFin = NULL;
    int* iCompteur = NULL;

    iPointeurDeb = &iTableau[0];
    
    iPointeurFin = &iTableau[TAILLE_MAX - 1];
    
    for(iCompteur = iPointeurDeb; iCompteur <= iPointeurFin; iCompteur++)
        if(*iCompteur == 0)
            printf("%d\n", iCompteur-iPointeurDeb);
}

Comment: Not in a comment, edit the question.  And make sure it's formatted properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`const int TAILLE_MAX = 10;` is not a compile-time expression in C, so it cannot be used as a compile-time array size. Replace the expression with a macro: `#define TAILLE_MAX 10`

See also [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40062767/why-in-c-a-const-object-is-not-a-compile-time-constant-expression).

Answer (score 0):

```
const int something = 100;
```

does not make the `something` a constant expression. It is constant variable but not constant expression.

Static storage duration objects sizes and initializers have to be `constant expressions`

> An integer constant  expression`*` shall  have  integer  type  and  shall
> only  have  operands that are integer constants, enumeration
> constants, character constants, sizeof expressions  whose  results
> are  integer  constants,  and  floating  constants  that  are  the
> immediate operands of casts. Cast operators in an integer constant
> expression shall only convert  arithmetic  types  to  integer  types,
> except  as  part  of  an  operand  to  the sizeof operator.
>
> (`*`)An  integer  constant  expression  is  required  in  a  number  of
> contexts  such  as  the  size  of  a  bit-field member  of  a
> structure,  the  value  of  an  enumeration  constant,  and  the  size
> of  a  non-variable  length array. Further constraints that apply to
> the integer constant expressions used in conditional-inclusion
> preprocessing directives are discussed in 6.10.1

In your case change it to:

```
#define TAILLE_MAX  10
```