# C - Initializing an array using variables with set values

Tags: c, arrays, compiler-errors

I'm trying to initialize an array using already defined variables, for extensibility reasons.

Here are the calls that I'm making:

```
int dung_width = 160;
int dung_height = 105;

char dungeon[dung_height][dung_width];
```

I'm getting the error that dungeon is variably modified at file scope.
Is this even possible and is this the best way of doing it?

P.S. I'm just starting C programming.

Comment: What compiler / version?  Also, can you produce a full example?

Comment: VLA can not be used with file scope. If the dimension number is a constant, You can like this `enum { dung_width = 160, dung_height = 105}; char dungeon[dung_height][dung_width];`

Comment: Variable-length arrays are only allowed inside functions.

Comment: Try defining these variables as `const`.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It is not valid in C.

Comment: @dbush I'm just using cygwin, but I'm not sure of the version. Here's a screen shot of the compliler: [link](http://imgur.com/a/rCjzU)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY You are right.. that's a surprise.. Found this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848537/can-a-const-variable-be-used-to-declare-the-size-of-an-array-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this they will not trouble you if they are constants:

```
#define dung_width  160
#define dung_height  105

char dungeon[dung_height][dung_width];
```

Comment: I don't prefer `const` for beginners macros are best!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY #define is allowed in C

Comment: const qualifier is allowed in C too @BLUEPIXY

Comment: @BLUEPIXY again check your link DEMO

Comment: @CoolVirus What's wrong with the DEMO? It is showing error.

Comment: You can't use const in this scenario but we can use const in C for declaring constants . @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Please indicate C source compilable source with using _const_.

Comment: I talk about _you can also use const to specify this as a constant so that it won't let your compiler for a compilation error._

Comment: @ChandlerF.Davis Accept and upvote if you find my answer correct this will be helpful for me.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY there was a comment before that which was deleted So I think that creates some Confusion