# C++ typedef int arr[x][y] fails in stackdump error

Tags: c++

I got the problem, that I have a given type I must use, that is defined like

```
const int width=800, height=800;     
typedef int field[width][height];
```

Now when I try to make in instance of this type, I only get an Exception.

To hold it easy, the program just looks like this:

```
  const int width=800, height=800;     
    typedef int field[width][height];  

    int main(){
        field f; 
    }
```

When I compile and link it, everythings fine, but when I'm going to run the progrma I get

```
0 [unknown (0x25D0)] test 4660 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to test.exe.stackdump
```

Comment: You can use macro constant to define the width and height instead of const int.

Comment: Are you using C or C++? Why have you shown an error message describing where a stack trace is accessible to you, but not shown the trace itself?

Comment: The size of this array is 2.44MB, that is probably too large for the stack.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer That "can" should be a "must", since using an `int` (`const` or not) for a statically sized array is not allowed; at best, OP will get a variable-length array instead of the statically sized one they presumably wanted. But that's not the specific problem here.

Comment: @underscore_d true, here the problem is more about the size of the array.

Comment: @underscore_d You're mistaken. A `const int` can very well be used as a constant expression, as long as it's not a non-static class member. The code compiles fine in all major compilers, and the type of `field` will be `int[800][800]`.

Comment: @oisyn No, you're mistaken. See [Can a const variable be used to declare the size of an array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848537/can-a-const-variable-be-used-to-declare-the-size-of-an-array-in-c) It's not interesting what "all major compilers" do, if you've not specified that you've compiled in a Standard mode with warnings on, etc.

Comment: @underscore_d This is not C, this is C++ (according to tag and title). And in C++, an intialized `const int` is a [Constant expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression). See also [[expr.const](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const)] of the C++ standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, your program runs out of stack space.

Either make the declaration global (move it out of `main ()` into global scope) or find out how you can increase stack space allocated to your program.

Comment: Or use `new` to allocate the array in heap memory instead of stack memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I would not recommend using `new` though. A `std::vector<std::array<int, width>>` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @oisyn sure  that is the *safe* way to manage it. Doesn't change the fact that `new` is used under the hood.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Regardless, "use new" shouldn't be used as advice for somewhone who is clearly still learning. See also [R.11](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rr-newdelete) of the C++ Core Guidelines.