# Problem to print out the result from memcpy

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, printf, memcpy

I am trying to use `memcpy` to pick out a specific range of data which I am interested, like using the syntax from `Matlab array(100:200)`. However, when I tried to print out the result to check if the function did right or not, I got an error: `Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF4A921399 (vcruntime140d.dll) in Examplefordebug.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.` Any thought to solve this problem? The result suppose to be two `5` from the array `ch2Buffer`

Here is the example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i,n;
    const int u32Size = 10;
    float* ch1Buffer = NULL;
    double* ch2Buffer = NULL;
    double* ch2newBuffer = NULL;
    
    int pBuffer[u32Size] = {10,2,10,2,10,5,10,5,10,2};
    int* pi16Buffer = pBuffer;

    ch1Buffer = (float*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof* ch1Buffer);
    ch2Buffer = (double*)calloc(u32Size, sizeof* ch2Buffer);
    

    // De-interveal the data to ch1Buffer and ch2Buffer
    for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
    {
        ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2];
        ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2 + 1];
    }

    // Use memcpy to pick out the data we are interested
    memcpy(ch2newBuffer, &ch2Buffer[2], 2 * sizeof(ch2Buffer[0]));



    // Print out to check the result
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%f ", ch2newBuffer[i]);
    }

    free(ch1Buffer);
    free(ch2Buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ``memcpy(ch2newBuffer,`` – you are copying into a pointer variable that is NULL as the destination has never been allocated. Therefore you get a NULL pointer dereference.

Comment: So do you mean the `ch2newBuffer` have to be declared to other format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000. Any thought to solve this problem?"*

Yes, your code is attempting to write to a memory location for which the process does not yet own...
You have a declaration here:

```
double* ch2newBuffer = NULL;
```

Then an attempt to copy an object to it:

```
memcpy(ch2newBuffer, &ch2Buffer[2], 2 * sizeof(ch2Buffer[0]));
```

*Without allocating memory first*.  Allocating memory will address the problem.

Add a 3rd memory allocation, and check the result of each before attempting to use the buffer. Some additional suggestions, [don't cast the return of (m)(c)(re)alloc() in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/645128), and do not use memory created with `[m][c][re]alloc()` without first verifying that the call was successful.  Here is a refactored section including these suggestions:

```
ch1Buffer = calloc(u32Size, sizeof* ch1Buffer);
if(ch1Buffer)
{
    ch2Buffer = calloc(u32Size, sizeof* ch2Buffer);
    if(ch2Buffer)
    {
        ch2newBuffer = calloc(u32Size, sizeof* ch2Buffer);
        if(ch2newBuffer)
        {
            // De-interveal the data to ch1Buffer and ch2Buffer
            for (i = 0; i < u32Size/2; i++)
            {
                ch1Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2];
                ch2Buffer[i] += pi16Buffer[i * 2 + 1];
            }

            // Use memcpy to pick out the data we are interested
            memcpy(ch2newBuffer, &ch2Buffer[2], 2 * sizeof(ch2Buffer[0]));



            // Print out to check the result
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                printf("%f ", ch2newBuffer[i]);
            }
            free(ch2newBuffer); 
        }else {/*handle error*/}
        free(ch2Buffer);
    }else {/*handle error*/}
    free(ch1Buffer);
}else {/*handle error*/}
```

One additional potential issue...  Depending on your compiler, you may have registered an additional error here:

```
 const int u32Size = 10;
 ...
 int pBuffer[u32Size] = {10,2,10,2,10,5,10,5,10,2};
```

A variable sized object [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) (defined in C99, and optionally in compilers since then.)   may not be initialized at declaration. ([read more about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18848537/645128))

Declaration can be done as following for a non-VLA array with initializer can be in several forms:

```
#define U32_SIZE 10

 int pBuffer[10] = {10,2,10,2,10,5,10,5,10,2};
 int pBuffer[U32_SIZE] = {10,2,10,2,10,5,10,5,10,2};
 int pBuffer[] = {10,2,10,2,10,5,10,5,10,2};
```

Or the following for a VLA (which cannot be initialized, and can only be declared within automatic scope.)

```
 int iBuffer[] = {10,2,10,2,10,5,10,5,10,2};//non-VLA for illustration
 int pBuffer[u32Size];//VLA 
 memcpy(pBuffer, iBuffer, sizeof(iBuffer);//update VLA with contents of iBuffer.
```

Comment: Hi thanks for point out. I tried the last part you wrote, but the problem didn't get solve

Comment: @Kevin - did you do what I suggested to do?  (_" Allocating memory will address the problem."_.  When I ran your code after allocating memory ( `ch2newBuffer = calloc(u32Size, sizeof* ch2Buffer);`  ) it worked just fine.  i.e. the error you asked for help on is no longer there.  Do you have another problem you are speaking of?

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't figure out it. Yes! it works!