# Can someone explain why it gives me this excess element array error?

Tags: arrays, c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
int n = 8;
int vettore[n] = {15,3,6,2, 12,13,14,10};
printf("%d", vettore[0]);
}
```

It gives me the error:excess elements in array initializer
int vettore[n] = {15,3,6,2 12,13,14,10};
Pls someone help me!

Comment: @anatolyg: This is not a duplicate of [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848537/can-a-const-variable-be-used-to-declare-the-size-of-an-array-in-c). The reported compiler message asserts excess elements, not a variable array length. None of the current versions of GCC, Clang, and MSVC on Godbolt report such an error message for the code in the question, for either C or C++, so this is a probably reporting error by OP, not a duplicate question.

Comment: The code in the question does not appear to produce the error message in the question. Check that you are compiling exactly that code and getting that error message. If there was a mistake, update the question with the code that gets the message. Also state the name and version of the compiler you are using and the command-line switches used to compile.

Answer (score -1):

In c array dimension declaration must be a constant but in your case it's a variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define n 8 //define a constant
int main ()
{
    int vettore[n] = {15,3,6,2,12,13,14,10};

    printf("%d", vettore[0]);
}
```

Comment: This does not explain the error message reported in the question.

Comment: He got that error because he's using a variable to declare the dimension of an array.

Comment: No, using a variable to specify the dimension of an array should result in either a message that variable length arrays are not supported or a message that variable length arrays may not be initialized, depending on circumstances. Testing with GCC, Clang, and MSVC shows it does not result in a message “excess elements in array initializer”.

Comment: Try it in codeblocks and you'll get it.