# Anonymous vs Defined Enums

Tags: objective-c, c, enums

Although I have experience with Enums in Java, typedef and Objective-C / C style enums are new to me. I can't seem to grasp the difference between enums with the names declared in the beginning and enums with the names not declared. For example:

```
typedef enum Months {JAN, FEB, MAR, APR}
    Months;
```

vs.

```
typedef enum {JAN, FEB, MAR, APR}
    Months;
```

is there a reason to ever pick the former form over the latter? The former seems to be redundant by stating 'Months' twice.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157181/in-which-situations-anonymous-enum-should-be-used) Looks very similar but it doesn't have the name at the end so I don't know if it is answering the same question.

Comment: Generally speaking, the compiler's okay with either one, but in my experience many libraries use the first option for clarity purposes. Also, it's `typedef`, rather than `typdef`

Comment: It should also be noted that you should use typedef NS_ENUM(type, enumName) for compile-time enum type safety.

Comment: I don't understand how this is a duplicate. The accepted answer suggests that we use the former over the latter or the macro as suggested by @paulrehkugler but I was asking why you would ever use the former over the latter which I am still not sure of after reading the other article. Is it just for historical significance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a general basis

```
typedef enum <tagname 1>
{
//values

}<tagname2>;
```

`<tagname 1>` is used to define more clarity about what your enum is all about

while `<tagname2>` is just a reference name  which contains the whole reference of `typedef enum <tagname 1>`

compiler supports both of the variations

Comment: Thanks cyberworm, one question though regarding your response: How does <tagname 1> provide more clarity? Are they ever used with different names?

Comment: as per the guidelines you have to tagname1 is used to give more meaning ful information about the enum